# Windows automatically disconnects faulty external harddrive making it difficult for repair

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My previous windows 11 instalation was on a seagate 1TB hardrive. Which went faulty. IM trying to scavenge for files. However whenever i connect my drive to my PC and open disk drill, after sometime the blue light on my harddrive connector stops blinking and disk drill disconnects. Indicating windows has probably cut off my drive. How can i fix this so i can disk drill my drive for files??
//edit
It stays connected on my windows 8 machine.

Comment: *Indicating windows has probably cut off my drive* Unlikely. It seems a failure of the USB-SATA interface.

Comment: But the USB SATA interface works well with my other healthy harddrive.

Comment: If so what's failing is the HDD's circuitry. For the purpose of file recovery it's the same problem or worse.

Comment: I stays connected on my hp mini running windows 8 tho

Comment: Here's  a suggestion: When asking a question post all the relevant information. You can also [edit] it latter to to add something. This isn't a forum.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But with the provided information what do you think is wrong?

Comment: Save your files with whatever computer the disk works well, then replace it.